# dpkg dependency problem

Tags: upgrade, kernel, 20.04, dpkg, dependencies

I was trying to upgrade my kernel to 5.5 following the instructions here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/01/install-kernel-5-5-ubuntu/. I downloaded the packages, but when I try to install them using the command `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` I get the following error:

```
(Reading database ... 180196 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-5.5.0-050500_5.5.0-050500.202001262030_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.5.0-050500 (5.5.0-050500.202001262030) over (5.5.0-050500.202001262030) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-5.5.0-050500-generic_5.5.0-050500.202001262030_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.5.0-050500-generic (5.5.0-050500.202001262030) over (5.5.0-050500.202001262030) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-unsigned-5.5.0-050500-generic.
Preparing to unpack linux-image-unsigned-5.5.0-050500-generic_5.5.0-050500.202001262030_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-unsigned-5.5.0-050500-generic (5.5.0-050500.202001262030) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-modules-5.5.0-050500-lowlatency_5.5.0-050500.202001262030_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-5.5.0-050500-lowlatency (5.5.0-050500.202001262030) over (5.5.0-050500.202001262030) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.5.0-050500 (5.5.0-050500.202001262030) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.5.0-050500-generic (5.5.0-050500.202001262030) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-unsigned-5.5.0-050500-generic:
 linux-image-unsigned-5.5.0-050500-generic depends on linux-modules-5.5.0-050500-generic; however:
  Package linux-modules-5.5.0-050500-generic is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-unsigned-5.5.0-050500-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-modules-5.5.0-050500-lowlatency (5.5.0-050500.202001262030) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-unsigned-5.5.0-050500-generic
```

I looked around the forum, but I can't find a solution to my problem. My kernel version is 5.4.0-42-generic. The reason I'm trying to upgrade to 5.5 is because my internet is running ridiculously slow (like dial-up slow) in Ubuntu 20.04. I know it is not my internet, as I get a perfect connection with my other computer. A solution provided by another user was to change kernel version (either upgrade or downgrade). Please, let me know if there is any other info that you need.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You downloaded wrong package. You downloaded `generic` version of `linux-image` and `linux-headers` but `lowlatency` version of `linux-modules` . `generic` and `lowlatency` aren't compatible and is entirely different. You downloaded `linux-modules-5.5.0-050500-lowlatency` which isn't correct package. You must download `linux-modules-5.5.0-050500-generic` and install that.